# Change \baselinestretch using xparse in TeX Live 2012

Tags: latex3, xparse

Is there a preferred way to change `\baselinestretch` using the xparse package included in TeX Live 2012? (I believe this is xparse version 3570, dated 2012/04/23.)

If I run `latex -output-format pdf document.tex` on Mac OS X 10.7.4 to create a PDF from this document—

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand \baselinestretch {} {1}
\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```

—pdfTeX never exits. Interrupting pdfTeX produces this output, which for the most part I do not understand—

```
! Interruption.
\size@update ...relax \baselineskip \f@linespread 
                                                  \baselineskip \normalbasel...
l.4 \begin{document}
```

If I replace `\RenewDocumentCommand \baselinestretch {} {1}` with `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}` to obtain—

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\begin{document}
hello, world
\end{document}
```

—then pdfTeX finishes and a PDF is produced. Also, using `\RenewDocumentCommand` in xparse version 2219 (2011/04/08) seems to behave as expected.

(I understand that `\baselinestretch` is 1 by default; I am using 1 in the examples for the sake of simplicity.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\baselinestretch` macro is used by LaTeX2e as a variable, not as a 'command'. It is used in places where it needs to expanded by TeX. The `xparse` functions (`\RenewDocumentCommand` and so on) produce non-expandable commands, for good reasons, but this is not intended to be used for variables. At the moment, there is no native LaTeX3 interface for setting these variables (indeed, it's not clear at present exactly how these variables should be handled in a systematic way). Thus you should use `\newcommand` for setting `\baselinestrech` and similar variables in LaTeX2e.

Comment: Will the command `\cs_set:Npn` do the job?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Well yes it will, but that's because `\cs_set:Npn` is TeX's `\def` renamed: does not make it good document level syntax.

Comment: Does this apply to `\arraystretch` as well?

Comment: @azetina Yes, applies to any macros used as variables

Comment: @azetina Yes, applies to any macros used as variables